# Get first item and last item if it exists from a group

Tags: linq, entity-framework, group-by

I have a scenario where my data looks like this.

```
Books
---------------------------------
title            | returnedDate
Great Gatsby     | 2015-05-04
Great Gatsby     | 2015-03-22
Great Gatsby     | 2015-01-11
Life of PI       | 2015-04-04
Life of PI       | 2015-04-02
Clean Code       | 2015-06-05
```

I would like to return the most first and last book in each group (grouped by title) in a single linq statement.  I know I can get the first or last item with a linq query like this.

```
var books = dbContext.Books
    .GroupBy(b => b.title)
    .Select(g => g.OrderDescending().FirstOrDefault());
```

How can I get the last item if one exists as well?

My final result would look like:

```
Books
---------------------------------
title            | returnedDate
Great Gatsby     | 2015-05-04
Great Gatsby     | 2015-01-11
Life of PI       | 2015-04-04
Life of PI       | 2015-04-02
Clean Code       | 2015-06-05
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a bit of fiddling I came up with this. Not sure how efficient this will be when dealing with a large table of data.

```
        [Test]
    public void FirstLastLinq()
    {
        var books = new List<Book> 
        { 
            new Book { Title = "Great Gatsby", Returned=new DateTime(2015,04,03) },
            new Book { Title = "Great Gatsby", Returned=new DateTime(2015,04,02) },
            new Book { Title = "Great Gatsby", Returned=new DateTime(2015,04,01) },
            new Book { Title = "Life of PI", Returned=new DateTime(2015,03,05) },
            new Book { Title = "Life of PI", Returned=new DateTime(2015,03,04) },
            new Book { Title = "Clean Code", Returned=new DateTime(2015,02,02) },
        };

        var newBooks = books.GroupBy(b => b.Title).SelectMany(g => g.OrderByDescending(b => b.Returned)
            .Where(b1 => b1.Returned == g.Min(b2 => b2.Returned) || 
                (b1.Returned == g.Max(b3 => b3.Returned) && g.Min(b4 => b4.Returned) != g.Max(b5 => b5.Returned))));

        Assert.IsNotNull(newBooks);

    }
    private class Book 
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public DateTime Returned { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var books = dbContext.Books
    .GroupBy(b => b.title)
    .Select(g=>new {
       Title=g.Key,
       First=g.OrderByDescending(x=>x).FirstOrDefault(),
       Last=g.OrderBy(x=>x).FirstOrDefault()
     });

Results:
title                  | First | Last 
Great Gatsby | 2015-05-04 | 2015-01-11
Life of PI         | 2015-04-04 | 2015-04-02
Clean Code    | 2015-06-05 | 2015-06-05
```

If you really want it like you asked, then it becomes a bit more difficult:

```
var books = dbContext.Books
    .GroupBy(b => b.title)
    .Select(g=>new {
       title=g.Key,
       returnedDate=g.OrderByDescending(x=>x).FirstOrDefault()
     }).Concat(
      dbContext.Books
      .GroupBy(b => b.title)
      .Where(g=>g.Count()>1)
      .Select(g=>new {
         title=g.Key,
         returnedDate=g.OrderBy(x=>x).FirstOrDefault()
       })
      ).OrderBy(c=>c.title).ThenDescendingBy(c=>c.returnedDate);
```

Yuck. Probably a better way, but first that came to mind.

Comment: Ouch that looks pretty scary.  Thanks for the answer anyway.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible by getting the first and last return date and then returning the books of which the return dates are equal to these:

```
from b in dbContext.Books
group b by b.title into bg
let first = bg.OrderByDescending (b => b.returnedDate).FirstOrDefault().returnedDate
let last = bg.OrderBy (b => b.returnedDate).FirstOrDefault().returnedDate
from b in bg
where b.returnedDate == first || b.returnedDate == last
orderby b.title, b.returnedDate
select b
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Gert.  I wanted to return the original Book object and not an anonymous object